# Removing badge subview from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I am adding a badge to a UIBarButtonItem... which works fine.  But I cannot remove it.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Code:

```
MKNumberBadgeView *badge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, -10, 30,30)];
badge.value = @"!";
badge.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
badge.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
badge.tag = 42;

if ([self.chatCount isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    [chatButton addSubview:badge];
} else {
    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews] ) { if (view.tag == 42 ) { [view removeFromSuperview]; } }
    [badge release];

}

UIBarButtonItem *chat = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:chatButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = chat;
[chat release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding your badge as a subview to chatButton not self.view.  Your for loop is iterating over self.view.subviews and badge is not a subview of self.view but a subview of chatbutton.  You will either have to iterate over chatButton.subviews or create a recursive method that iterates over all subviews.  Alternatively, you can use [viewWithTag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a) which I think searches the entire hierarchy.

I would just hold an instance variable to badge and call [self.badge removeFromSuperview] or self.badge.hidden = YES;